# Reveal a small splash screen, before fading to main content

Tags: jquery

See this website [here](http://www.papermakestack.com/)

There is a small splash which fades out revealing the page.

How is this animation done exactly?

Can you just use jQuery `fadein` and `fadeout`? Something like this perhaps? Then just have splash `z-index:500`?

```
<div id="splash"></div>
<div id="bodycontainer" style="display: none"></div>


$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#splash').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#bodycontainer').fadeIn('fast');

    });
});
```

I would be very gateful for some guidance here.

Comment: Why don't you create a div with fixed position (for example the splash elem you created), 100% height and width after the opening of the body with the higher z-index and what you want inside it. Then on window load, you set a timeout of 2 seconds and you fade it out

Comment: Unless you _really_ need to hide the page while loading content in the background, _please_ don't implement this; I hate "splash screens" on web sites and I'm sure I'm not the only person...